# What does a switch do with invalid VLAN tagged traffic?

Tags: networking

Say you're plugged into a switch that allows TAGGED 2; and treats UNTAGGED 5.

However, say you tag your traffic 10... which isn't "valid" on that port.

What happens to any traffic you send?

Answer (score 2):

It is ignored. It's perfectly normal for a switch to handle only a subset of the VLANs used on some of its connected ports.